# Determine maximum length of repetitive sequence in synchronous FSM

Tags: digital-logic, boolean-algebra, synchronous

I have the following realisation:

[image]

The figure shows a synchronous circuit with the clock on Rising Edge. The circuit will generate a sequence of values on the output (abcde) of the five D-flip-flops.
For \$t=0\$ the output abcde = \$"10000"\$.

I am asked to determine the length of the maximum repetitive sequence of the circuit, but I don't know how to.

I have the answer to this question, and it turns out that the longest sequence has a length of 16. But there is no explanation of how you arrive at this answer. Can someone clarify how the procedure is done?

Comment: Do you know what a permutation group is?

Comment: No, I haven't heard that term before. Although it sounds like something belonging to group-theory?

Comment: Yeah, your circuit basically implements a simplified version of a CRC calculator (simplified as in the input is constant), so you can find the CRC polynomial and calculate the cycle length of the corresponding permutation group.

Comment: Is that really the only way to do this? It seems like a very advanced method.

Comment: No idea, it's the way I would do it, but my guess would be that the constant input would give a simpler procedure, which is why I only commented instead of answered, so it can just be deleted when someone gives you the easy solution.

Comment: Oh okay, I appreciate your comments though.

Comment: Actually, 16 is NOT the correct answer. This circuit generates two possible sequences: it either outputs "00000" continuously, or it goes through up to 15 other states before repeating.